# is there a way to list used variables?

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

Let's say I have a basic go text/template:

```
{{.var}} is another {{.var2}}
```

I want to get an array of the variables names used in the template, to be able to skip the execution if they are not available in the data I pass to execute, is it possible to do that somehow?

As my data is not a struct but a map, doing .var will always return something: if it doesn't exist, it will return an empty string when I would have hoped to get an error when executing the template.

So for the example from above, I would have liked to get:

```
[var var2]
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, do you mean to ask how you can check if something was nil? Or rather how to loop through the map, by (key, value) pair?

Comment: @user114241 No, I'm asking if there's a way to get the list of variables used in a go template, before execution.

Comment: I mean the only variables accessible in a text/template are those that you pass in when you `Execute()`... Sorry, maybe I just haven't had enough coffee yet this afternoon.

Comment: @user114241 no That's me who's not able to explain what I want. I want to get the **names** of the variables used in the template without having to change anything in the template. But that's alright I did that another way that I'll explain in an answer later. Thanks anyways

Comment: @user114241 I explained a little bit more in the question, I hope it's a bit more understandable.

Comment: Ah kk, honestly I would keep a []string that contains the names of the variables that are set in your map. Then in the template, you can range over the []string and use the value to index into your map. If you want the template to not compile at all though if variables are not set you may want to look at [soy](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/) and the go implementation of it [robfig/soy](https://github.com/robfig/soy) (you can have templates fail to compile if @params in soy docs are not provided/set).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a template func that returns an error if a value isn't set. Something like this:

```
template.FuncMap(map[string]interface{}{
    "require": func(val interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        if val == nil {
            return nil, errors.New("Required value not set.")
        }
        return val, nil
    },
})
```

Then in your template:

```
{{require .Value}}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/qZMBID7Y8L

Comment: Yes I forgot to answer my own question but that's actually what I did as what I wanted to do seems to be impossible! Thanks!